# postmessage in an exe

Tags: c#, winapi, messaging

after i use process.start() a form1 appears on the desktop. When i click the form2 button from form1 a new form appears. how can i postmessage in form2? can someone please give me an example? I think i need to use FindWindow, but i don't know what to write as parameters. thx

Questions:

1. is there a way i can search in my application the elements from the form1 list (which appears after i run process.start in my app) and print them?
2. is there a way i can double click programatically an element from form1 - which automatically generates form2?
3. is there a way to postmessage in form2?
   thx

i am using user32.dll

Comment: What do you mean by "I am using user32.dll"? Lots of Windows applications use user32.dll. It's a core WinAPI file used to build user interfaces.

Comment: I think he means he is using the FindWindow or functions like that in User32.dll

Comment: imean i am using FindWindowsEx(), PostMessage()..and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [White](http://white.codeplex.com/) framework provides all the functionality you're seeking. It is commonly used for UI testing, but it can be used for any kind of UI automation.

Comment: ar there any examples? as i see there are just dll-s . how can i use them?

Comment: @elisa: You need to add a reference to the dlls from your C# project. In Visual Studio you right click the project and click "Add Reference...". As for examples, you can start [here](http://white.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Get%20Started&referringTitle=Home) and [here](http://white.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Programming%20using%20white&referringTitle=Home). (I'm still learning it, as I only became aware of it yesterday, but it seems pretty simple.)

Comment: ok, thx Marthino. I am going to look over it. Could we keep in touch. Could you give me your mail address plz? Maybe we'll find the answer to my questions in 2-3 days. Thx

Comment: how can i search for all contacts in a list using white?

Comment: You need to get the list, with `window.Get`, and then use the UIItem retrieved to get it. There are examples [here](http://white.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=UI%20Items&referringTitle=Programming%20using%20white).

Comment: i did lunch the application and after that i use getwindow(??) . is there a way to get all the windows without specifing what exactly to get? i am asking this because i run getwindows("main") and i have the error that there is no main. I don't know what's the name of the process that handles the users i have in my exe

Comment: in white recorder.exe  it says private white.core.ulitems.panel chorme toolbar